# Updating a parent entity insert new entry

Tags: hibernate, jpa, inheritance, hibernate-mapping

I have an `EndangeredFish` entity that extends `Fish` entity with JOINED inheritance type.

After some time we want to update the `Fish` to an `EndangeredFish` (with `numberOfSpeciesLeft` field).

```
Fish fish = fishRepository.findOne(fishId);
EndangeredFish endangeredFish = fishToEndangeredFish.apply(fish);

endangeredFish.setNumberOfSpeciesLeft(500);
endangeredFish.setId(fishId);

Fish updatedFish = fishRepository.save(endangeredFish);
```

This inserts a new entry in the `ENDANGERED_FISH` table (as expected), but also **inserts a new entry in the `FISH` table, which I don't expect**.

I wonder if my case is suited for entity inheritance or I should just use one `FISH` table with `null` `numbOfSpeciesLeft` field at the start and update it later.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Fish {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Integer numOfFins;

    private String color;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Environment environment;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn
    private String parts

}


@Entity
public class EndangeredFish extends Fish {
    Integer numOfFishLeft;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your entity classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder if my case is suited for entity inheritance or I should just use one FISH table with `null` numbOfSpeciesLeft field at the start and update it later.

No, it is not a suitable case for inheritance. If you have an instance that should basically change its type during its lifecycle you are using inheritance wrong.

A `null` value for `numbOfSpeciesLeft` sounds like a reasonable start. It might evolve into an optional reference to `EndangermentInformation` if you have more information to keep track of. That could be mapped as a one-to-one relationship or as an embeddable.